# accuracy as a function of precision and recall

Tags: machine-learning, precision, precision-recall

I know that:

```
Accuracy = TP+TN/TP+FP+FN+TN

Precision = TP/TP+FP

Recall = TP/TP+FN
```

But I want to know if there is any way to compute *accuracy* given only *precision* and *recall* values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything using only precision and recall but this works fine for me:

[image: Accuracy]

Comment: What do you mean by the right term in the denominator